# What kind of mount is best for a 100lb 85 inch tv?

Tags: mounting, television

I have an 85inch Samsung QLED TV that weights around 100 lbs. I'm planning on mounting it on a wall with metal studs. I was wondering if I should get a full motion mount or a tilt mount. What do you suggest? What are the pros and cons of each type of mount? Thanks!

P.S.: I came across information on various websites stating that when using full motion mounts, the weight of the TV is completely supported by the mount itself and not the studs. On the other hand, tilt mounts evenly distribute the weight. I was uncertain about the accuracy of this information, which is why I wanted to understand the advantages and disadvantages of these two types of mounts.

Comment: I am flagging it as opinion based.  It's your choice.  If you want to watch it mostly from an acute angle then get a full motion mount. It is more pricey and more bulky.

Comment: Thank you for responding, Rohit! I came across information on various websites stating that when using full motion mounts, the weight of the TV is completely supported by the mount itself and not the studs. On the other hand, tilt mounts evenly distribute the weight. I was uncertain about the accuracy of this information, which is why I wanted to understand the advantages and disadvantages of these two types of mounts.

Comment: From a purely logical perspective, if "the weight of the TV is completely supported by the mount itself", then what is supporting the mount if not the studs in the wall? I'm not aware that the science of anti-gravity is sufficiently well-developed to be integrated into TV mounts (yet) ;) ...

Comment: @RohitGupta  With the metal studs(my understanding they do not hold as well), it  is probably a good question.  Full motion mount might be too much, but I do not  know enough about the metal studs.  With wood studs I would agree with you that it is an opinion type.

Comment: @brhans What I meant was that the weight of the TV is entirely supported by the full motion mount itself whereas with tilt mount the weight of the TV is evenly distributed across the mount and the stud since it's fixed to the wall. At least that's what I have understood from my research so far.

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding what you mean by "full motion mount" or "tilt mount", my point is that it makes no difference either way. The TV is attached to the mount, so the mount bears the full weight of the TV, and in turn the mount is attached to the (stud in the) wall, so the (studs in the) wall bear the full weight of both the TV + mount. Having a different type of mount between the TV and the wall does not (and can not) remove any of the weight of the TV from the wall. ...

Comment: ... Using a tilt mount where the bottom edge of the TV rests against the wall does not move any of the weight-bearing between the mount and the wall - the entire weight of the TV is still supported by the mount, which is in turn supported by the wall.

Comment: The answer is: the kind of mount the manufacturer rates for 100 lb TVs.

Answer (score 2):

Like most things, it depends.

If you have perfect wall/room placement for a tilt, tilt mounts are generally half the price as full motion mounts and a great option.

If you can't mount a tilt where you want the TV centered, full motion offers forgiveness as you can move the TV to your ideal placement.

Support is carried on what you attach it to either way. No matter which way you go:

1. make sure the mount supports the size and weight of the TV
2. make sure you install the mount and TV according to the instructions

Preference wise, I like the full motion mounts.

1. I find them much easier to get behind to plug in cables
2. It allows you to change room orientation a bit and still get ideal viewing angles.